# How to write the chapter caption side by side with the \rlap command?

Tags: chapters

I tried `minipage` without success

```
\documentclass{book}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage[paperwidth=190mm,
               paperheight=230mm,
               textheight=180mm,
               lmargin=30mm,
               rmargin=30mm]{geometry}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}
   \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\large\raggedleft} 
   {\vspace{2mm}\hfill\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
        \bfseries\Large first chapter\hspace{2mm}\\[1.5mm]
        \bfseries\Large{#1}
              \end{tabular}
    \rlap{\rule{30mm}{15mm}}
    }{-15mm}{}{}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{titulo de capitulo muito longo, mas muito longo mesmo!}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{minipage}{100mm}
   {\itshape introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto introducao ao texto.}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{center}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
  texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto.

  texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto.
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By `chapter caption` you mean the chapter number?

Comment: no. it is the text. i'd like the black box beside the text.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, something that is not using `titlesec`. A similar thing needs to be done for unnumbered chapters if there should be a need for it.

[image: alexandreChapterTitle]

```
\documentclass[
twocolumn,
openany
]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=190mm,
paperheight=230mm,
textheight=180mm,
lmargin=30mm,
rmargin=30mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\renewcommand{\chapIntroText}{}}{}{}
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{50pt}%
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedleft \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \Large\bfseries \Ordinalstring{chapter}\space \@chapapp
        \par\nobreak
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries #1\smash{\rlap{\hspace{1em}\rule{3cm}{1.5cm}}}\par\nobreak
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
    \normalfont\normalsize\itshape\chapIntroText
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
  }
}
  \makeatother
\newcommand{\chapIntroText}{}
\newcommand{\defChapIntro}[1]{\renewcommand{\chapIntroText}{#1}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\defChapIntro{We are introducing this chapter here. This chapter is like a zoo, there is a Wombat. Over there is a Capybara. Look, a Mara! Oh, and a Duck is swimming on the pond}
\chapter[surprise chapter]{This is a long chapter title with a little surprise}
\blindtext[4]

%\defChapIntro{This is much shorter}
\chapter{Welcome to Monkey Town, the most fun and crazy town on earth}
\blindtext[4]
\addtocounter{chapter}{5200}
\chapter{Wombat}
\end{document}
```